# product has a custom options or not in magento?

Tags: magento

how to check that product has a custom options or not in magento?

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);         
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku, 'sku');
$code = $product->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku, 'sku');
$hasOptions = $product->hasCustomOptions();
```

Simple as that. At the end `$hasOptions` should be `true` or `false`.

Comment: There is an error in Magento where `hasOptions` or `hasCustomOptions` will (sometimes) return `false` every time. Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30832285/1330505