# how to check product has custom options?

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to check whether product has custom options or not in code (my code runs `sales_order_place_after` event). 
I have try below code but it does not returning anything.
`$product->hasCustomOptions()`
and
`$product->hasOptions()`

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Marius You have answered similar question at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745879/product-has-a-custom-options-or-not-in-magento So may be you can help me

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/check-product-has-options-in-magento-2/ check the link.

Answer (score 14):

I've encountered this error more times than I care to count. Either `$_product->hasOptions()` or `$_product->hasCustomOptions()` always returns `false`. I still don't know why this error occurs.

Anyway, you can get the same result by doing the following. For configurable products:

```
<?php if ( $_product->getData('has_options') ): ?>
    <!-- do something -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

And to get the same result for simple products with custom options:

```
<?php if ( $_product->getData('has_options') && ($_product->getTypeID() == 'simple') ): ?>
    <!-- do something -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope that helps a future adventurer!

---

**EDIT**

---

The solution above does not work in loops when the **flat category** data option is enabled in Magento, and we don't want to reload the product inside the foreach loop!!

Instead, we can check for custom options using the following singleton inside the loop:

```
$opts = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
$optsSize = $opts->getSize();

if ( $optsSize ) {
    ... // go go go
}
```

Comment: but why $_product->hasOptions() won't work ?, seems like this is the natural call to do

Answer (score 6):

use the method `$product->getHasOptions()`